# Could not read json from api Flutter, null result

Tags: flutter, dart

i am beginner in Flutter , i was constructing an app with api of soccer , after execution i found that i am not getting the result of the json that i access , i don't know how to access to this kind of json in flutter (just a sample , the full schema is on the url in my code

```
{
    "id": 18,
    "area": {
        "id": 2088,
        "name": "Germany"
    },
    "name": "Borussia Mönchengladbach",
    "shortName": "M'gladbach",
    "tla": "BMG",
    "crestUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Borussia_M%C3%B6nchengladbach_logo.svg",
    "address": "Hennes-Weisweiler-Allee 1 Mönchengladbach 41179",
    "phone": "+49 (02161) 92930",
    "website": "http://www.borussia.de",
    "email": "info@borussia.de",
    "founded": 1900,
    "clubColors": "Black / White / Green",
    "venue": "Stadion im Borussia-Park",
}
```

so after i executed i got a lot of errors

```
  Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Reloaded 12 of 1304 libraries in 1 158ms.
E/flutter ( 1379): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 1379): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 1379): Tried calling: []("venue")
E/flutter ( 1379): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter ( 1379): #1      _ClubDetailsState.getClub.<anonymous closure> (package:tl_fantasy/clubs/club_details.dart:49:20)
E/flutter ( 1379): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1244:30)
E/flutter ( 1379): #3      _ClubDetailsState.getClub (package:tl_fantasy/clubs/club_details.dart:47:5)
E/flutter ( 1379): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1379): #4      _ClubDetailsState.initState (package:tl_fantasy/clubs/club_details.dart:58:5)
E/flutter ( 1379): #5      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
E/flutter ( 1379): #6      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
E/flutter ( 1379): #7      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #8      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter ( 1379): #9      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter ( 1379): #12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
E/flutter ( 1379): #13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
E/flutter ( 1379): #14     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5)
E/flutter ( 1379): #15     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
E/flutter ( 1379): #16     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #17     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter ( 1379): #18     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #19     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #20     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter ( 1379): #21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #22     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #23     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter ( 1379): #24     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
E/flutter ( 1379): #25     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
E/flutter ( 1379): #26     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
E/flutter ( 1379): #27     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5)
E/flutter ( 1379): #28     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4791:11)
E/flutter ( 1379): #29     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
E/flutter ( 1379): #30     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter ( 1379): #32     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #33     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #34     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter ( 1379): #35     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #36     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
E/flutter ( 1379): #38     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
E/flutter ( 1379): #39     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
E/flutter ( 1379): #40     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
E/flutter ( 1379): #41     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5)
E/flutter ( 1379): #42     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4791:11)
E/flutter ( 1379): #43     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
E/flutter ( 1379): #44     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
E/flutter ( 1379): #45    
F/crash_dump32(10829): crash_dump.cpp:246] target died before we could attach (received main tid = 10827)
F/crash_dump32(10928): crash_dump.cpp:246] target died before we could attach (received main tid = 10926)
F/crash_dump32(11371): crash_dump.cpp:246] target died before we could attach (received main tid = 11369)
F/crash_dump32(11458): crash_dump.cpp:246] target died before we could attach (received main tid = 11456)
```

Here what i have tried:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'club_arguments.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';


class ClubDetails extends StatefulWidget {

   int id;
   String name;
   String image;
   String rank;
   String nationality;
   String stadium;
   String manager;
   String wins;
   String draws;
   String losses;
   int goals;
   int goalsIn;


   ClubDetails({ this.id, this.name,this.image,this.rank,this.nationality,this.stadium,this.manager,this.wins,this.draws,this.losses,this.goals,this.goalsIn});

  @override
  _ClubDetailsState createState() => _ClubDetailsState();
}

class _ClubDetailsState extends State<ClubDetails> {

  String stadium;
  String founded;


  getClub(int id) async {
    
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'http://api.football-data.org/v2/teams/$id',
        headers: {'X-Auth-Token': '86014f6025ae430dba078acc94bb2647'});
    String body = response.body;
    Map data = jsonDecode(body);


    //Club(this.id,this.name,this.image,this.rank,this.nationality,this.stadium,this.manager,this.wins,this.draws,this.losses,this.goals,this.goalsIn);
    setState(() {

      print(data[0]['venue']);
      print(data[0]['founded']);
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getClub(widget.id);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Titles> titles = [
      Titles("LA LIGA", "Spain","Barcelona","2008" ),
    ];


    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Club Info"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                  colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.blue])
          ),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.black38])),
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child:    Card(
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child:
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            child:
                            SvgPicture.network(widget.image,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width:10.0),
                          Spacer(),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: <Widget> [
                              Text(widget.name, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              )),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                              Text("rank : "+widget.rank, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              )),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                              Text("Found : "+widget.manager, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                              )),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                              Text("Nationality : "+widget.nationality, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                              )),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                              Text("Stadium : "+widget.stadium, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                              )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 10),
                  child:  Text(
                    "Achieved Titles",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return Card(
                        elevation: 4.0,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child:
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://www.impacttrophies.co.uk/content/images/thumbs/0065685_tower-football-trophy-gold.jpeg"),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width:10.0),
                              Spacer(),
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                children: <Widget> [
                                  Text(titles[index].name, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                  )),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                                  Text("country : "+titles[index].country, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                                  )),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                                  Text("club : "+titles[index].club, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                                  )),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                                  Text("year : "+titles[index].year, style: TextStyle( fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.grey[600],
                                  )),
                                ],
                              ),

                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: titles.length,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 70,
                ),
              ],
            ),

          )
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Stats{

  String title;
  String result;

  Stats(this.title,this.result);

}

class Team {

  String name;
  String image;
  String date;

  Team(this.name,this.image,this.date);

}


class Titles {
  String name;
  String country;
  String club;
  String year;

  Titles(this.name,this.country,this.club,this.year);

}

class Club {

  int id;
  String name;
  String image;
  String rank;
  String nationality;
  String stadium;
  String manager;
  String wins;
  String draws;
  String losses;
  int goals;
  int goalsIn;


  Club(this.id, this.name, this.image, this.rank, this.nationality,
      this.stadium, this.manager, this.wins, this.draws, this.losses,
      this.goals, this.goalsIn);

}
```

I am trying to learn how to get this single json result of 'venue' and of 'founded' , and also if it is possible to know if there are other errors

Comment: An error caused by this string `final ClubArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;`. Since you don't use `args` in your code, just delete this string and try again.

Comment: the problem that you mentioned is solved , but now the json is null ,when printing, i will edit my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bro, your app has some errors, check your logic. Respect to API:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:wnetworking/wnetworking.dart';

class FootballData {
  static const _base = 'http://api.football-data.org';
  static const _apiKey = '86014f6025ae430dba078acc94bb2647';

  static Future<void> fetchTeamById(int id) async {
    final url = '$_base/v2/teams/$id';

    stdout.write('Start fetching...');
    await HttpReqService.getJson<Map<String, dynamic>>(url, headers: {'X-Auth-Token': _apiKey})
      .then((response) {
        if (response != null) {
          print('done!\n');
          print('Team: ${response['name']}');
          print('Venue: ${response['venue']}');
          print('Founded: ${response['founded']}');
        }
      })
      .whenComplete(() => print('...'));
  }
}


void main(List<String> args) async {
  await FootballData.fetchTeamById(18);
  print('Job done!');
}
```

Result:

```
Start fetching...done!

Team: Borussia Mönchengladbach
Venue: Stadion im Borussia-Park
Founded: 1900
...
Job done!
```

Moreover you don't need to create classes if you work in one-way (this case), only you need to know more about the data structure returned and get only the important parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to make model/pojo class,

https://app.quicktype.io  // make sure you selected dart on right side,
then just use

> model.fromJson(jsonValue);

to parse data.

Comment: that did not help me to understand why i got a null value

Comment: ok i created the pojo class model now , how to use it , show me please , i need an example of how to use it , how can i call it in my request ?

Answer (score 0):

your API call is not returning an array, so I don't know why you used `data[0]['venue']`, instead you should be using `data['venue']`